# Share JFrame variable with JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have one `JFrame` in `main.java` and one `JInternalFrame` in `login.java`.

In `main.java`, there are two menu items present: `login` and `logout`.

At first, `login` is enabled and `logout` is disabled. When I click on `login` it will open a login page and after successful login, I want to enable `logout`.

How do I enable `logout`?

Comment: Use an observer pattern to generate notifications about changes to the state to interested people - before you ask, a ActionListener is a demonstration of a observer pattern. If you wanted to, you could use a ChangeListener or PropertyChangeListener or create your own based on your needs